# Get all content as string inside div

Tags: javascript, html, selector, scrape

I need to get all content inside an HTML element, including all child nodes and grandchild nodes and their content as if it was a string. This is my expected output:

`<div class="images"><div class="img_100"><a class="img a" legenda="" target="" style=""><img src="/img/site/570/b/random_image.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum - dolor sit amet" class="portrait"></a></div></div>`

I am currently using JS with puppeteer to scrape the page I need, but I need all the HTML as string to format some content and I don't know how to get this the way I want.

I also used this query `document.querySelectorAll(".page_content_post")` to get the parent element I want the content and child/grandchild nodes from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's really not enough information there to go on.  At least post the full html of the element you are trying to target (you just have the innerHTML).  Preferably, give a representative sample of the page's HTML structure, if not the entire thing, or a link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get parent by class:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.page_content_post').innerHTML
```

to get parent by ID:

```
document.getElementById('#page_content_post').innerHTML
```